# Distribute python script as standalone application

Tags: python, qt

I wrote a small script to adapt the export txt file from anobii (a small social network for readers, very popular in Italy) to Goodreads (the larger social network for readers, I suppose). I did it for myself and a few friends, so I ran it from the command line; but I suppose there may be other people interested, so I was wondering how could I embed it as a distributable application. I know it is possible because a very popular application for e-book management, Calibre, is mainly written in Python, uses Qt and it is distributed as a standalone application both for Windows and Linux, but I don't know how complex this is. I know, I can check documentation and try to work it out by myself, but if somebody could give me some hints it would be very helpful.

I should also add that I would *love* to add such a programming technique to my bag-of-tricks :)

Comment: try py2exe , if you're on windows that is...

Comment: Well, windows will surely be the primary installation target, so I can indeed try it, when I'm at work tomorrow (I have no WIndows installation at home...)

Comment: Mmmh, I had a look at the documentation, [providing the Microsoft Visual C runtime DLL](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5) may be a problem. Also, I am using Python 3.5 which is not mentioned at all...

Comment: Indeed! I don't know how I could miss it :( thank you!

Comment: Still, some year have passed, maybe there is something new around? In the meantime, I'll and study pyinstaller, which looks very promising :)